# Set UILabel Text From Plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

I successfully got my plist arrays and dictionaries loaded into my tables.  I am trying to set the exerciseName value to a UILabel in my exercise's detail view.

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>exercises</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>exerciseDetail</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>exerciseName</key>
            <string>Ab Crunch Machine</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>exerciseDetail</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>exerciseName</key>
            <string>Ab Roller</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>muscleName</key>
    <string>Abdominals</string>
</dict>
```

The exercise Detail is blank right now but will eventually load a UILabel or UITextView in the same exercises's detail view.

Im guessing I need to do some thing like

```
label.text =[[self.exerciseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"exercises"];
```

EDIT:

For my exerciseViewController didSelectIndexAtRow I have:

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [def setObject:exerciseArray forKey:@"exercises"];
    [def setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] forKey:@"exercises"];
```

and for ViewDidLoad for detailViewController i have:
    viewDidLoad for exerciseDetailView

```
 self.navigationItem.title = @"Exercise Detail"; 

NSMutableArray *exerciseDetailArray = [[[NSUserDefaults alloc] objectForKey:@"exercises"] mutableCopy];

int indexValue = [[[NSUserDefaults alloc] valueForKey:@"exercises"] intValue];

name.text =[[exerciseDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];
```

Console Output:

```
2011-03-19 22:52:08.279 Curl[32300:207] exercisedetalarray: (
    {
    exerciseDetail = "";
    exerciseName = "Ab Crunch Machine";
},
    {
    exerciseDetail = "";
    exerciseName = "Ab Roller";
},
    {
    exerciseDetail = "";
    exerciseName = "Advanced Kettlebell Windmill";
},
    {
    exerciseName = "Air Bike";
},
    {
    exerciseName = "Alternate Heel Touchers";
},
    {
    exerciseName = "Barbell Ab Rollout";
},
    {
    exerciseName = "Barbell Side Bend";
},
    {
    exerciseName = "Bent Press";
},
    {
    exerciseName = "Bent-Knee Hip Raise";
},
    {
    exerciseName = "Butt-Ups";
},
    {
    exerciseName = "Cable Crunch";
}
```

)

```
2011-03-19 22:52:08.280 Curl[32300:207] index value: 0
```

Edit with MaserView NSDefault code:

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[def setObject:exerciseArray forKey:@"InfoArray"];
[def setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] forKey:@"indexVal"];
```

Edit with detailView NSUserDefaults code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    NSMutableArray *exerciseDetailArray = [[[NSUserDefaults alloc] objectForKey:@"InfoArray"] mutableCopy];

    int indexValue = [[[NSUserDefaults alloc] valueForKey:@"indexVal"] intValue];

    name.text =[[exerciseDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Faisal:

Looking at your code I suppose that your labels are under your tableView as you are using `indexPath.row` for indexing the array

Your Idea looks Correct.

**STEP-1:**

Retrieve Data from plist into your Array (**Plist -> Array**)

Let us say if your plist name is `Exercise.plist`, then you can use the following code to retrieve your data into plist

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Exercise" ofType:@"plist"];
exerciseArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

**STEP-2:**

Get Data from Array into label's text (**Array -> Label Text**)

Then set the UILabel's text from the array values using below code

```
label.text =[[exerciseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"exercises"];
```

**NOTE:**

For using the same array between you masterView and detailView, you can set your array in NSUserDefaults on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in your masterView and retrieve the same array in detailView.

You can do this using following code:

In masterView on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[def setObject:exerciseArray forKey:@"InfoArray"];
[def setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] forKey:@"indexVal"];
```

You can retrieve that array in detailView using below code:

```
NSMutableArray *exerciseDetailArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"InfoArray"] mutableCopy];

int indexValue = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"indexVal"] intValue];

label.text =[[exerciseDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"exercises"];
```

OR

```
NSArray *exerciseDetailArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfArray:[[NSUserDefaults alloc] objectForKey:@"InfoArray"]];

int indexValue = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"indexVal"] intValue];

label.text =[[exerciseDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"exercises"];
```

Hope this helps you :)

**FINAL EDIT:**

Replace your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method with below method in `SpecificExerciseTableViewController.m`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
     detailViewController.exerciseArray = [[self.exerciseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"exercises"];
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.


    NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [def setObject:exerciseArray forKey:@"InfoArray"];
    [def setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] forKey:@"indexVal"];
    NSLog(@"Index inexpath:%d",indexPath.row);
    int indexValue = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"indexVal"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"index value master view: %d",indexValue);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];

}
```

This would surely work :)

Comment: ahh actually forgot to mention that there is no table in the exercise detail view nib.  thats why the index.row isn't working in this class.  The nib is simply a black view with a ui label and a picture.  So because of this, I think I need to refrain from using any mention of index.row

Comment: Yeah in that case you can even pass indexPath.row using `NSUserDefaults` from masterView to detailView in the same way as I have shown for the array.

Comment: @Faisal: I have edited my answer. So please look at how to use NSUserDefaults to pass the index and Array from masterView to detailView and then use that particular `indexValue` to retrieve data into your detailView. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Ok thanks.  And is it supposed to be     `label.text =[[exerciseDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];`

Comment: @Faisal: Yeah right that is what it needs to be in your detailView. sorry it was just a mistake on my part.

Comment: Ok I understand what you are saying.  For some reason it is not working it must be one of my Keys are wrong.

Comment: @Faisal: I have changed that in my answer. Hope now it is clear.

Comment: @Faisal: Yeah may be. Try to print your `exerciseDetailArray` and `indexValue` in NSLog using `NSLog(@"%@",exerciseDetailArray);` and `NSLog(@"%d",indexValue);`

Comment: ok ill try that, i just updated original post with the exact code I'm using so it can be compared to the plist I posted. thanks!

Comment: @Faisal: Does it print the value of `exerciseDetailArray` and `indexValue` properly in Console?

Comment: @Faisal: Do try to put the code for retrieving array and indexValue in detailView on `viewWillAppear` and not on `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Im embedding the console output in original post. Thanks

Comment: Hey in NSUserDefaults you cannot use key as `excercises` for both `execiseArray` and `indexPath.row`. Try using two different keys for storing the array and indexPath.row in NSUserDefaults

Comment: @Faisal: Hey so is the console output is correct as per your selection? is the indexValue correct?

Comment: I think you're referring to my old code, I'm no using the code from your answer so the keys are different for both (one is exercises, other is indexval)

Comment: @Faisal: Ok fine. so now what do you get in detailView?

Comment: Well the UILabel is not updating with the value from exerciseName.  (thats the only thing its supposed to do).  I am using the viewWillLoad method.  Are the console outputs ok?

Comment: yeah it looks ok. is the `indexValue` fine? is it supposed to be 0?

Comment: @Faisal: You should be using `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`.

Comment: Yeah that's the one I'm using. But maybe I have to return YES or 1?

Comment: Hey then just check that you have connected the outlets properly to your label.

Comment: And yes index value is 0 sorry.

Comment: Also try and put the NSLog on label.text after you assign it the execiseName. See what value it shows in console?

Comment: Ok not a problem..  you dont have to pass value for `animated` as YES or 1. It needs to be as it is.

Comment: Ok I got it.  I changed to `label.text =[[exerciseDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"exercisesName"]; `

Comment: ok so the UILabel is updated but the text isn't always correct. its showing the wrong names sometimes...

Comment: try to put NSLog(@"%@",[[exerciseDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"exerciseName"]) before you assign it to label.See what it gives. So that we can guess whether array has a problem or label has a problem

Comment: Like if I click the cell that says "bicep curl", the ui in the detail view should also say "bicep curl".  But right now it seems like its randomly choosing names from the array to load to the UILabel.

Comment: so now I suppose there is a problem with the indexPath.row value that passes. Check the value for indexValue everytime and try and print the exercisesName from the array for that indexValue in Console.

Comment: so did it help you get your problem solved? does it work correctly now?

Comment: Ok so the index row is correctly showing the right exerciseName.  I think the problem is when I click a cell, it is not always loading the right index.  So if I click cell that should yield index of 4, it may randomly load index of 2.

Comment: When I click a cell in the table view it is not brining up the correct index data, therefore I think the error is in the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

Comment: yeah check the indexPath.row value in Console in masterView and compare it with indexValue in detailView.

Comment: Ok, so the index views between the two views are NOT matching.

Comment: Seems some problem with the way you have set and retrieved indexValue from NSUserDefaults for that. Can you please post that portion of your code?

Comment: the indexPath.row in masterView is correct, but not the indexValue in detailView.

Comment: ok this code looks fine and how to retrieve the indexValue on detailView? can you post that code also?

Comment: @Faisal : try using this to retrieve the indexValue on `viewWillAppear` on detailView:  `int indexValue = [[[NSUserDefaults alloc] objectForKey:@"indexVal"] intValue];` and see if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately Parth,the issue is still there.  Maybe it has to do with my plist having a dictionary instead of an array?

Comment: did you just try "Clean All" and then "Build and Go"?

Comment: Im using xcode 4 so the I did a "clean" and then "run" which I think is the same thing.

Comment: Is is ok if I add a link to my project and you can take a look at it?  I really appreciate it.

Comment: yeah in that case what you can do is retrieve your data from plist into a NSDictionary and then from `[[yourDictionaryName valueForKey:@"exercisesName"] objectAtIndex:indexValue];` in detailView and similarly you will have to replace your array with dictionary everywhere on masterView as well. If you still have more doubts just leave a comment here. :-)

Comment: @Faisal: yeah sure go ahead and just add a link of your project i will reveiew it in arnd 15 mins and leave you a response back soon.

Comment: hey your masterView is MusclesTableViewController?

Comment: Yes it is. The hierarchy is muscleViewController, then exerciseViewControler, then finally detailViewController.

Comment: Wait i have got the solution. It has got it working :) I am just posting the code now to my answer

Comment: @Faisal : fine you are most welcome. See the `FINAL EDIT` section of my answer and replace the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method with the one I have given in `SpecificExerciseTableViewController.m`. The problem in your code was that you were pushing the detailView before setting the NSUserDEfaults. You should first set the NSUserDefaults and then push the view.

Comment: Oh, ok.  That makes sense.  I can't believe I overlooked that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Faisal: yeah it was a small logical mistake which can really make things go mad..(Example: it took us 51 comments and 1 answer with 3 edits to solve this logical error). Anyways all is well that ends well :) :) Right? Hope this helped you. Did it help you? is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  My problem is solved 100% thanks to you, Parth.

Comment: @Faisal: Yeah I am glad that it helped you brada :-)

Comment: @faisal- Looking at the effort that @PARTH has done. +1 for him from my side.Hope you too give a +1 vote to him. 52 comments does some doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Julia. I just try to help others with the little bit of what I know. :-)

Comment: @ParthBhatt Hi, I'm trying to combine what you have here with something else I [found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149172/pass-data-from-plist-based-uitableview-to-uiviewcontroller), but can't seem to get it right. I get an error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x0)` at `NSMutableArray *content = [[[NSUserDefaults alloc] objectForKey:@"InfoArray"] mutableCopy];`. I've looked through the page more than a couple times and read all the comments but it isn't working. I was wondering if maybe you could look at my project too?

Comment: @R3TRI8UTI0N: Can you give a link to your code? That way I can help you analyze root cause of the issue.

Comment: @ParthBhatt I sure can: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yryeokqyrlgswjz/LOLExplorer.zip?dl=0
To expand on my problem, I get that error when tapping on a cell in my TableViewController (champList), which should take me to the corresponding ViewController (champView). Also, when tapping the Additional Information button at the bottom of champView, that should also pass the same plist (so that more information for the same cell can be provided) Currently, only the first two cells have data that can be passed.

Comment: @ParthBhatt Hi, just wondering how that's going and if you need anything from me

Comment: @R3TRI8UTI0N: Sorry actually I am a bit busy with work. Haven't got a chance to review it. Would review your code in weekend and would let you know where the issue is.

Comment: @ParthBhatt Hi, just checking in!

Comment: @R3TRI8UTI0N: I had been a bit unwell. So will check on this weekend. Extremely Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @ParthBhatt I believe I have figured it out, thanks for your answer above.