# Pass data from plist based UITableView to UIViewController

Tags: iphone, class, uitableview, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass data to detail view after being selected in a table view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562258/how-to-pass-data-to-detail-view-after-being-selected-in-a-table-view)

I have a TableViewController with a protoptype cell. It's populated with Labels and ImageViews from a .plist with an Array of Dictionaries. How can I pass this data to the detail View? The detail view is a UIViewController subclass.
I've tried with methods from different tutorials but I just can't find the right combination to make it work. Code examples would be great!

WinesViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class WineObject;

@interface WinesViewController : UITableViewController {
    WineObject *wine;
}

@end
```

WinesViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
wine = [[WineObject alloc] initWithLibraryName:@"Wine"];
self.title = @"Vinene";
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [wine libraryCount];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"wineCell";

//UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
WineCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...

cell.nameLabel.text = [[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
cell.districtLabel.text = [[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"District"];
cell.countryLabel.text = [[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Country"];
cell.bottleImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image"]];

return cell;
}
```

wineobject.m

```
@implementation WineObject 
@synthesize libraryContent, libraryPlist;

- (id)initWithLibraryName:(NSString *)libraryName {
if (self = [super init]) {
    libraryPlist = libraryName;
    libraryContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                                              pathForResource:libraryPlist ofType:@"plist"]];
}
return self;
}


- (NSDictionary *)libraryItemAtIndex:(int)index {
return (libraryContent != nil && [libraryContent count] > 0 && index < [libraryContent count]) 
? [libraryContent objectAtIndex:index]
: nil;
}

- (int)libraryCount {
return (libraryContent != nil) ? [libraryContent count] : 0;
}

- (void) dealloc {
if (libraryContent) [libraryContent release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

WineCell.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WineCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *districtLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *countryLabel;

@end
```

Comment: do you have the tableView's dataSource property set up?  you can do this in IB/storyboard, or you can do it in code ... though i don't see it in this code.  if it's not set up, then tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is never going to get called.  another possibility is that, in viewWillAppear: , you may have to call [self.tableView reloadData] after the wine objects are populated from the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinesViewController.m
You can just pass the dictionary to the detail view, no ? Maybe something like this:

```
#import "WineDetailViewController.h"

@interface WinesViewController()
@property (nonatomic, retain) WineDetailViewController *wineDetailViewController;
@end

@implementation WinesViewController
@synthetize wineDetailViewController

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];    

    // This will give us the wine dictionary
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    if (wineDetailViewController == nil) {
      // Init the wine detail view
      wineDetailViewController = [WineDetailViewController alloc] init];  
    }
    // Here you pass the dictionary
    wineDetailViewController.wineDictionary = dictionary;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:wineDetailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

WineDetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface WineDetailViewController : UIViewController {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *wineDictionary;
@end
```

WineDetailViewController.m

```
@implementation WineDetailViewController
@synthetize wineDictionary;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  // Here you access the wine dictionary
  NSString *country = [wineDictionary objectForKey:@"country"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried accessing the dictionary this way in the viewDidAppear: countryLabel.text = [wineDictionary objectForKey:@"Country"]; after making the outlet but that didn't show anything. When i try NSString *country = [wineDictionary objectForKey:@"country"]; it sais that country is an unused vaiable. Any suggestions for how set it up? (I'm new to this so it takes a while to get it)

Comment: It's telling country is an unused variable because it's not used. Try to put a NSLog like this

NSString *country = [wineDictionary objectForKey:@"country"];
NSLog(@"country = %@", country);

What do you get there?